# can srcgen4javasssit be used to generate source code of my existing class?

Tags: java, javassist

i am working with **javassist** and willing to regenerate the **source code** / alter the classes. but the problem is that i am unable to find a library to generate source code of my existing classes from .class file and then use javassist to edit them. 
i want a library to use in my project to generate the source code from existing class and then modify it. 
while searching web, i cam to know about http://www.fuin.org/srcgen4javassist srcgen4javassist  but i am unable to use it for my existing classes. can u guide plz ?

Answer (score 1):

Javassist is a framework to modify **JVM byte code** that means you do not modify the **source code** (.java file) but rather the **byte code** (.class file).

On the other hand if what you really want is to **decompile classes**, by other words generate java source files from the bytecode, my suggestion is to use [JD decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) which also has an eclipse plugin which can help you a lot.

I don't know srcgen4javassist, so I won't  comment on that project, but I can assure you that JD won't let you down.

Comment: @adeeliqbal: my suggestion in that case is to understand which java patterns you want to change understand and modify the bytecode pattern directly. You probably already have your patterns defined, edit your answer with one or two examples of previous code and the modified code and I'll try guide you through the injection process.

Comment: thanks for your support. i want to share an idea. what about decompiling (using JAD or JODE etc)  from java through command line and then reading the file in a string through filereader?

Comment: @adeeliqbal: that can also be an option, although in my opinion I think bytecode manipulation would be better, because code decompilation might not be always possible and even when it is it might decompile with errors.

Comment: i have used JODE to decompile it. thanks for ur support. it works !

Comment: @adeeliqbal: glad I could help you out in some way. Good luck with your project